# JavaFX add objects with controller class

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a `JavaFX` `FXML` which includes a `ScrollPane`, after the Application launches it gets Information out of the `Internet`, and with that it creates 500 HBoxes which contain the Information in three `String` and an `Icon`, but how can I create `JavaFX` ojects inside the `controller` `class` and can I use a `fxml` `template` for that? For easier understanding, it works like a App Store that creates a object for each App

Comment: You might want to have a look at this [Consuming REST service and displaying the data in front-end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233068/javafx-consuming-rest-service-and-displaying-the-data-in-front-end/30238735#30238735)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to bind your parent container (BorderPane, AnchorPane, or whatever you use) in the controller and then you can let your controller implement the `Initializable` interface and the needed method `void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources)`.

In this method, you can add your HBoxes by using `parent.getChildren().add(myHbox)`.